# Mediarecorder Video RTP/RTSP Streams!

Tags: android, video, camera, rtsp, rtp

I am able to Record Android's Camera Using Mediarecorder Class.

I heard that sipdroid (videocamera.java ) sends the recorded video as RTP streams.

I tried that and able to do the same.

But how do i receive the RTP streams and play it in PC?

I too heard that in Sipdroid,on the server (PBXes )side they were converting these streams into RTSP streams and passing it back to videocamera.java file.

Can anyone help me in converting RTP Streams to RTSP streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an [RTSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326) stream, RTSP is a session management protocol (as is SIP) and lets you setup streaming using [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550). Amongst other things the port numbers are communicated during session initiation. When RTSP is used, the actual media is still sent using RTP. Read the RFCs for more info on either protocol.